# MACOS / MySQL / SQL Developer connection error - timezone issue

Tags: mysql, macos-sierra

On my Mac PC, I have installed MySQL and SQL Developer as well as the MySQL Connector/J, the official JDBC driver for MySQL, so that the MySQL tab appears in the connection window of SQL Developer.

In the SQL Developer connection window, I am filling in the following details

Connection name: test
Username : root
Password: xxxxx

In the MySql tab within this connection window, the hostname and port is auto populates the values localhost and 3306.

There is a button called 'Choose Database', when I click on this button I am getting the below error message in red color

"Status : Failure - The server time zone value 'AEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone.  You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support"

How do I fix this issue so that I can connect to the MySql database from SQL developer?

PS: I am currently based in Sydney, Australia.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved by adding the below entries in the below mentioned file.  In the new mysql database installations, this file would not be present so create the file so you will have create new plain text file with root privileges.  When you start the MySQL server, this file will be read every time.  The value specified below is a global parameter.

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone='+10:00'
```

The single quotes should typed in not copy pasted.

And then restart the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Upvote to Nitin Puthran's answer.

If you have a Homebrew installation of mysql, my.cnf is in the Cellar mySql directory (not etc). For my version this is:

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.41/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone='+10:00'
```

And restart the mySql server.

Answer (score 0):

I installed MySQL 8 with native packages on Mojave (10.14.6). As far as I can tell, there is no such thing as a my.cnf file. I couldn't get MySQL to recognize any my.cnf file, even by specifying one on the configuration tab of the MySQL settings applet in System Preferences. The only thing that worked for me was editing `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` and adding `<string>--default-time-zone=America/Denver</string>` to the `Program Arguments` section. Either restart your Mac or use the aforementioned applet to restart the server.

I imagine using a city name will only work if you have loaded timezone data into MySQL. `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql` worked for me. Otherwise an offset like the above answers should work.